# How to do this in Android? (C# Source)

Tags: c#, android, json

The objective is to send data over an HTTP Post with JSON in it.
The C# Source does like this:

```
Http.AddFileField("file", "file.text", ms);
String json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d, Formatting.None, jSettings);
IOUtil.WriteStringToStream(json, ms);
ms.Position = 0;
```

How to do this on Android?

Comment: Android is not a programming language.

Comment: You would have to find the equivalent in Java, using the Android API

Comment: @BoltClock: If Monodroid answers are accepted the question and tag are valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
    HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;
    URL mUrl = new URL(url);
    urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
    urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/" + "json");
    urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
            //query is your json string
    if (query != null) 
            {
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",  Integer.toString(query.length()));
                urlConn.getOutputStream().write(query.getBytes("UTF8"));
            }
    urlConn.connect();
```

Comment: Perfect, just did everything i needed.